# How to change hover background on links in css?

Tags: html, css

When you hover the mouse over a link, it shows a background like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

I am currently on a Maven/web application project with the JSF Framework. And the links are generated by `<h:link>`. In regular html/css its easy to make it look the second pic, but It wont work with JSF. How should i do it?

Comment: post the code here so we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css for this would be

```
element:hover{
background: none;
text-decoration: underline;}
```

Replace element with the class or id of that html element.